# Как отрисовать карту из tiledmap в с++ в vs?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, разработка-игр, sfml, tilemap

Пишу курсовую на c++, в виде игры с видом сверху, где задача собирать по карте мусор и взаимодействовать с персонажами. Не понимаю как выгрузить карту с tiledmap в visual studio. Подскажите способы реализации. Через какие библиотеки можно сделать или как сделать парсинг xml файла. Это мой первый опыт в разработке, так что много не знаю.

Вот фото карты:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]